# how to select date in sql query

Tags: android

I added a lot of values in SQLite. How do I write query for searching dates earlier than today ?

Answer (score 1):

Further details are available in the [sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) ... but the following should be the sort of thing you're after.

```
SELECT columnA, columnB
FROM tableX
WHERE dateColumn < date('now')
```

If this doesn't help, you should look to post more details of your tables, related code, etc..